# Liferay portlet share session between users

Tags: session, liferay, session-state, portlet, liferay-6

I have developed a portlet for Liferay, after this I

- add new site
- add page
- setup portlet to page

I create a new user group and add the group to the site membership, and all users added to this group can see my site, but when they update page, latest session state of current user is loaded. I suggest session is shared between all users. I tried to use

```
<private-session-attributes>true</private-session-attributes>
```

but did not help. How to do, that each user will have own instance of session?

Comment: Can you please verify that you are testing with each user on a different browser?

Comment: Yes, I have verified it on different browser, with each user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used member variables in the portlet, instead of local variables. The answer is located at [liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12981953)